# 'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector

Tags: r

Stuck on an error in R.

```
    Error in names(x) <- value : 
      'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Yeah, and I strongly suspect you've pinpointed the wrong line... So some more context is required! Try typing `traceback()` after the error occurs.

Comment: Did you check this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153092/meaning-of-ddply-error-names-attribute-9-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vec

Answer (score 26):

In the spirit of @Chris W, just try to replicate the exact error you are getting. An example would have helped but maybe you're doing:

```
  x <- c(1,2)
  y <- c("a","b","c")
  names(x) <- y

Error in names(x) <- y : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

I suspect you're trying to give names to a vector (`x`)  that is shorter than your vector of names (`y`).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're doing in the loop, the fact that the `%in%` operator returns a vector might be an issue; consider a simple example:

```
c1 <- c("one","two","three","more","more")
c2 <- c("seven","five","three")

if(c1%in%c2) {
    print("hello")
}
```

then the following warning is issued:

```
Warning message:
In if (c1 %in% c2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

if something in your if statement is dependent on a specific number of elements, and they don't match, then it is possible to obtain the error you see

Answer (score 2):

I want to explain the error with an example below:

```
> names(lenses)
[1] "X1..1..1..1..1..3"
```

> names(lenses)=c("ID","Age","Sight","Astigmatism","Tear","Class")
>   Error in names(lenses) = c("ID", "Age", "Sight", "Astigmatism", "Tear",  : 
>     'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [1]

The error happened because of mismatch in a number of attributes. I only have one but trying to add 6 names. In this case, the error happens. See below the correct one:::::>>>>

```
> names(lenses)=c("ID")
> names(lenses)
```

> [1] "ID"

Now there was no error.

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen such error and i solved it. You may have missing values in your data set. Number of observations in every column must also be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had this, caused by a scaled numeric variable not being returned as numeric, but as a matrix. Restore any transformed variables to as.numeric() and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error for a silly reason, which I think was this:

Working in R Studio, if you try to assign a new object to an existing name, and you currently have an object with the existing name open with View(), it throws this error.

Close the object 'View' panel, and then it works.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake I made that coerced this error was attempting to rename a column in a loop that I was no longer selecting in my SQL. This could also be caused by trying to do the same thing in a column that you were *planning* to select. Make sure the column that you are trying to change actually exists.

Answer (score -1):

For me, this error was because I had some of my data titles were two names, I merged them in one name and all went well.