# Cut data and access groups to draw percentile lines

Tags: r, cut, percentile

I'm very new to R so please be gentle.

I have a dataset containing timestamps and some data.
Now I'd like to draw a graph where:

- The data is grouped by e.g. 60 mins intervals and
- some percentile lines are drawn.

I'd like to have a graph with the time as x-axis and the gap as y-axis.
I imagine something like boxplot but for a better overview - since I have a long measurement - instead of boxes I'd like to have lines that connect the

- mean values,
- 3 percentiles,
- 97 percentiles and
- 100 percentiles

Here's an example data:

```
> head(B, 10)
                        times     gaps
1  2013-06-10 15:40:02.654168 1.426180
2  2013-06-10 15:40:18.936882 2.246462
3  2013-06-10 15:40:35.215668 3.227132
4  2013-06-10 15:40:48.328785 1.331284
5  2013-06-10 15:40:53.809485 1.294128
6  2013-06-10 15:41:04.027745 2.292671
7  2013-06-10 15:41:25.876519 1.293501
8  2013-06-10 15:41:42.929280 1.342166
9  2013-06-10 15:42:11.700626 3.203901
10 2013-06-10 15:42:23.059550 1.304467
```

I can use cut to divide the data:

```
C <- table(cut(B, breaks="hour"))
```

or

```
C <- data.frame(cut(B, breaks="hour"))
```

But how can I draw the graph form this? I don't know how to access the gap values of the groups. Otherwise I could

```
quantile(C$gaps, c(.03, .5, .97, 1))
```

Thanks in advance for any help
Ramon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solid question.  I was pulling my hair out until I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153092/meaning-of-ddply-error-names-attribute-9-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vec) which described an interesting "feature" of `plyr`.  So this solution utilizes ggplot, plyr, reshape2- hopefully a good intro to R.  If you need to add cuts through days you can also do that by adding a variable in the ddply().

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
Hs <- read.table(
  header=TRUE, text='
dates times     gaps
1  2013-06-10 15:40:02.654168 1.426180
2  2013-06-10 15:40:18.936882 2.246462
3  2013-06-10 15:40:35.215668 3.227132
4  2013-06-10 15:40:48.328785 1.331284
5  2013-06-10 15:40:53.809485 1.294128
6  2013-06-10 15:41:04.027745 2.292671
7  2013-06-10 16:41:25.876519 1.293501
8  2013-06-10 16:41:42.929280 1.342166
9  2013-06-10 16:42:11.700626 3.203901
10 2013-06-10 16:42:23.059550 1.304467')
Hs$dates <- paste(Hs$date, Hs$times, sep = " ")
Hs$dates <- strptime(Hs$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
class(Hs$dates) # "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
Hs$h1 <- Hs$dates$hour
Hs$dates <- as.POSIXct(strptime(Hs$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
class(Hs$dates) # "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Hs, aes(factor(h1), gaps)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill="white", colour="darkgreen") # easy way!  Traditional boxplot.
ggplot(Hs, aes(factor(h1), gaps)) + geom_boxplot() +
      stat_boxplot(coef = 1.7, fill="white", colour="darkgreen")
```

I don't know if adding "coef = 1.7" works for you- 
if not continue further to create the values via a summary table

```
cuts <- c(.03, .5, .97, 1)
x <- ddply(Hs, .(h1), function (x)
{summarise(x, y = quantile(x$gaps, cuts))})
x$cuts <- cuts
x <- dcast(x, h1 ~ cuts, value.var = "y")
x.melt <- melt(x, id.vars = "h1")
```

Here are the lines you requested plus another box plot just for fun.

```
ggplot(x.melt, aes(x = h1, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_point(size = 5) + 
  geom_line() + scale_colour_brewer(palette="RdYlBu") + xlab("hours")
ggplot(x, aes(factor(h1),  ymin = 0, lower = `0.03`, middle = `0.5`,
                     upper = `0.97`, ymax = `1`)) + 
         geom_boxplot(stat = "identity", fill="white", colour="darkgreen")
```

[image: geom_line]

[image: custom boxplot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also learned about POSIXlt, class(), ddply(), summarise() and my question is answered as well :-) Thanks alot!