# Problems with difftime &plyr

Tags: r, datediff

I have the following data frame called workfile:

```
   head(workfile)  
                 times        users     signal log  
    14 2014-01-13 00:00:16 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
    28 2014-01-13 00:00:47 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
    42 2014-01-13 00:01:18 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
    56 2014-01-13 00:01:48 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
    70 2014-01-13 00:02:19 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
    84 2014-01-13 00:02:50 00250902DC7D   true  ON
```

I have 14 different users, essentially I would like to compute the time differences for each user. I am using ddply but it doesn't work and I don't understand the reason

```
hope<-ddply(workfile,.
.(users),transform,diff=c(difftime(tail(workfile$times,-1),head(workfile$times,-1)), NA))
```

here is the error message:
    ****Error in attributes(out) <- attributes(col) : 'names' attribute [9] must be the same length as the vector [8]****'

**In addition if I attach my dataframe and I launch the same command, it occurs that the error message changes:**
`attach(workfile)`

`hope<-ddply(workfile, .(users), transform, diff = c(difftime(tail(times, -1),head(times,-1)), NA))`

****Error in as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(time1) : invalid 'x' argument****
and it's quite strange that too...

I have noticed that, as far as the user (in the 3rd column) is the same, there is not any error. It occurs if I try with a dataframe with different users...Evidently my code is not correct in the part of `tail(...),head(...)`  My goal is to compute the time differences row by and distinctly for all the users...

I have used`dput` with a sample of my dataframe:

```
head(pino)  
> pino
                     times        users signal log  
319001 2014-01-16 21:57:46 00250902FA92   true  ON  
319006 2014-01-16 21:57:46 002509030E53   true  ON  
319007 2014-01-16 21:57:46 002509030C41   true  ON  
319011 2014-01-16 21:57:46 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
319014 2014-01-16 21:57:49 00250902FB05   true  ON  
319015 2014-01-16 21:57:49 00250902FA92   true  ON  
319020 2014-01-16 21:57:49 002509030E53   true  ON  
319021 2014-01-16 21:57:49 002509030C41   true  ON  
319025 2014-01-16 21:57:49 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
319028 2014-01-16 21:57:58 00250902FB05   true  ON  
319029 2014-01-16 21:57:58 00250902FA92   true  ON  
319034 2014-01-16 21:57:58 002509030E53   true  ON  
319035 2014-01-16 21:57:58 002509030C41   true  ON  
319039 2014-01-16 21:57:58 00250902DC7D   true  ON  
319042 2014-01-16 21:58:04 00250902FB05   true  ON  
319043 2014-01-16 21:58:04 00250902FA92   true  ON

> dput(pino)
 structure(list(times = structure(list(sec = c(46, 46, 46, 46, 
 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 4, 4), min = c(57L, 57L, 
 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 
 58L), hour = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), mday = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), mon = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
 year = c(114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 
 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), wday = c(4L, 
 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
 ), yday = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", 
 "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
 ), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), users = structure(c(3L, 13L, 
 10L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("00250902DC7D",
 "00250902FA91", "00250902FA92", "00250902FB05", "00250902FB2E", 
 "00250902FE0A", "00250902FE63", "002509030AD2", "002509030B9D", 
 "002509030C41", "002509030C8D", "002509030CE4", "002509030E53", 
 "002509030E63"), class = "factor"), signal = structure(c(2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("false", 
 "true"), class = "factor"), log = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("OFF", 
 "ON"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("times", "users", "signal", 
 "log"), row.names = c(319001L, 319006L, 319007L, 319011L, 319014L, 
 319015L, 319020L, 319021L, 319025L, 319028L, 319029L, 319034L, 
 319035L, 319039L, 319042L, 319043L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I have the following error message:

```
Error in attributes(out) <- attributes(col) : 
  'names' attribute [9] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: Rather than posting the console output you should post the results of `dput` on your object. The attributes are not printed by default so we don't really know what you are dealing with.

Comment: Really hard to know for sure without the data, but why don't you try: `diff=c(difftime(tail(times,-1),head(times,-1)), NA))`; note how I removed the `workfile$` parts, which I think will cause conflicts with transform since you're potentially trying to use the entire `times` vector instead of the piece subset by `ddply`.  I can't promise this is correct since I haven't tested it.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat, the dataframe is quite big...Can I `dput` even so?          @BrodieG, I need to compute the differences for all the users distinctly

Comment: Yes you can, or store just the head of it in a new object and dput it if it reproduces the problem, as the whole data frame

Comment: @Llopis I have done what you just suggested and the error occurs when I have different users...

Comment: Then copy here the dput of this sample, so other people can help you with their attributes

Comment: @Llopis I put it above.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat I posted the results of `dput` for a piece of my dataframe`

Comment: Ah. You have managed to make your times of POSIXlt class. That really messes things up. If you are going to work with datetimes in dataframes then you need to use POSIXct class. The reason is that a POSIXlt object is really much more complex and some functions such as `difftime` do not accept POSIXlt objects. (Why that should be seems strange to me, but that's the way it is.) The "-" operator does do subtraction of times but `difftime` throws an error.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat `POSIXlt` definitely messes things up, but I don't think the problem is `difftime` (my tests indicate that `difftime` works with `POSIXlt`). Even this won't work: `ddply(pino, .(users), transform, diff = I(users))`. Just having the `POSIXlt` as the index is enough to cause `ddply` to fail.

Comment: You're right about `difftime`. I was giving it the difference of two POSIXlt objects as it's first argument and it wasn't dispatching correctly, which now that I think about it is my failure. Too bad that I am the only one so far to upvote your insights here. @antonio ought to learn to give positive regard for the answers he is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, if you convert your time representation, your function will work:

```
# Fails
ddply(pino, .(users), transform, diff = c(difftime(tail(times, -1),head(times,-1)), NA))
# Convert time format
pino$times<-as.POSIXct(pino$times)  
# Works as expected
ddply(pino, .(users), transform, diff = c(difftime(tail(times, -1),head(times,-1)), NA))

#                  times        users signal log diff
# 1  2014-01-16 21:57:46 00250902DC7D   true  ON    3
# 2  2014-01-16 21:57:49 00250902DC7D   true  ON    9
# 3  2014-01-16 21:57:58 00250902DC7D   true  ON   NA
# 4  2014-01-16 21:57:46 00250902FA92   true  ON    3
# 5  2014-01-16 21:57:49 00250902FA92   true  ON    9
# 6  2014-01-16 21:57:58 00250902FA92   true  ON    6
# 7  2014-01-16 21:58:04 00250902FA92   true  ON   NA
# 8  2014-01-16 21:57:49 00250902FB05   true  ON    9
# 9  2014-01-16 21:57:58 00250902FB05   true  ON    6
# 10 2014-01-16 21:58:04 00250902FB05   true  ON   NA
# 11 2014-01-16 21:57:46 002509030C41   true  ON    3
# 12 2014-01-16 21:57:49 002509030C41   true  ON    9
# 13 2014-01-16 21:57:58 002509030C41   true  ON   NA
# 14 2014-01-16 21:57:46 002509030E53   true  ON    3
# 15 2014-01-16 21:57:49 002509030E53   true  ON    9
# 16 2014-01-16 21:57:58 002509030E53   true  ON   NA
```

I am not quite clear on why this works. This has been [mentioned before in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153092/meaning-of-ddply-error-names-attribute-9-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vec?rq=1), and @hadley just stated that you should use `POSIXct` and not `POSIXlt` in `data.frame`. I'm not clear as to why.

Comment: The bug seems similar to [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/5amu5_LdyK8)

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat & @nograpes, I have noticed 2 things too:        1) if `attach` my dataframe then it works even with `POSIXlt` and I don't know as to why...In addition before to attach it I have to create a new dataframe where the rows are in progressive order...if use the dataframe as subset from the starting one it doesn't work...   2)If I use `POSIXct`like both you suggested another error occurs as my dataframe is quite big...: `Error in data.frame(list(times = c(1389567616, 1389567647, 1389567678,:arguments imply differing number of rows: 34060, 152174`. and I don't know as why too..

Comment: First, don't use `attach`, it will just lead to more problems. Second, does `as.POSIXct` really only work correctly only on a smaller `data.frame`? It really should work for any size of `data.frame`.

Comment: I agree it is better not to use `attach`.How can I fix the fact the some times (`times = c(1389567616, 1389567647, 1389567678)`  imply differing number of rows: `34060, 152174`? It means that some times are the same for different users and for this reason `difftime` maybe gets crazy?

Comment: What is the `length(as.POSIXct(pino$times))` as compared to `length(pino$times)`? Are you sure you are typing `pino$times<-as.POSIXct(pino$times)`?

Comment: `pino` was only a portion of my original dataframe. `pino` works...if I use my entire dataframe then it fails

Comment: Okay, then substitute `pino` for whatever your big data.frame is called. What are the two lengths?