# aggregate POSIXct vector using plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I am attempting to write a ddply summarize statement that works on a vector of POSIXct times. for each user.nm I simply want to get the largest and smallest timestamp associated with their name. the data looks like so:

```
    test.data=structure(list(user.nm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), ip.addr.txt = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
    login.dt = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("11/20/2013", 
    "12/26/2013", "3/11/2013", "6/25/2013", "6/27/2013", "7/15/2013"
    ), class = "factor"), login.time = structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 
    1L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("10:16:17", "11:07:27", "13:22:32", 
    "13:55:05", "9:23:33", "9:49:23"), class = "factor"), login.sessn.ts = structure(c(1372180920, 
    1363024500, 1372340940, 1384960560, 1388074020, 1373894580
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), month = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Dec-2013", "Jul-2013", "Jun-2013", 
    "Mar-2013", "Nov-2013"), class = "factor"), quarter = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L), change.label = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("user.nm", "ip.addr.txt", "login.dt", 
"login.time", "login.sessn.ts", "month", "quarter", "change.label"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

the plyr statement looks like this:

```
user.changes=ddply(test.data, c("user.nm"), summarize, 
               change.count=sum(ip.label.txt),
               max.change.time=max(login.sessn.ts),
               min.change.time=min(login.sessn.ts))
```

and the error I'm getting is this:

```
Error in attributes(out) <- attributes(col) : 
  'names' attribute [9] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

I'm having some issues interpreting what this error actually means, and apparently [one person's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153092/meaning-of-ddply-error-names-attribute-9-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vec) involved converting the POSIXct class to character, which doesn't really work in my case.

could anyone shed some light on how to make this work? I'm open to other approaches as well, I just like the relative simplicity of ddply's syntax. I'll be working with more time-based data in the near future, so I would appreciate anyone's insight on how to approach this type of aggregation problem with other R-based tools.

Comment: I edited the plyr statement because it seemed to be referring to data and variables that you don't have in example

Answer (score 0):

I checked your data with `str`, and it turned out that your dates were actually factors. You can make them dates with `lubridate` :

```
library(lubridate)
test.data2 <- transform(test.data,lst = dmy_hm(login.sessn.ts))

ddply(test.data2, c("user.nm"), summarize, 
      change.count=sum(ip.addr.txt),
      max.change.time=max(lst),
      min.change.time=min(lst))

  user.nm change.count     max.change.time     min.change.time
1       a            3 2013-11-03 13:55:00 2013-01-06 12:03:44
2       b            3 2013-01-06 08:35:32 2013-01-06 08:35:32
3       c            4 2013-01-11 10:16:00 2013-01-11 10:16:00
4       d           10 2046-11-24 13:24:29 2013-01-12 11:08:04
```

Comment: unfortunately, lubridate won't work on my version of R (2.15.2).  also, that's my mistake with the sample data-I'll post new data shortly.  on my full dataset the class is definitely POSIXct