# R multiple columns group by

Tags: r, group-by, transform, shiny, strsplit

I have a dataset `x_output` that looks like this:

```
          timestamp   city wait_time weekday
2015-07-14 09:00:00 Boston       1.4 Tuesday
2015-07-14 09:01:00 Boston       2.5 Tuesday
2015-07-14 09:02:00 Boston       2.8 Tuesday
2015-07-14 09:03:00 Boston       1.6 Tuesday
2015-07-14 09:04:00 Boston       1.5 Tuesday
2015-07-14 09:05:00 Boston       1.4 Wednesday
```

I would like to find the mean `wait_time`, grouped by `city`, `weekday`, and `time`. Basically, given your city, what is the average wait time for Monday, for example? Then Tuesday?

I'm having difficulty creating the `time` column given `x_output$timestamp`; I'm currently using:

```
x_output$time <- strsplit(as.character(x_output$timestamp), split = " ")[[1]][2]
```

However, that simply puts "09:00" in every row, not the correct time for each individual row.

Secondly, I need to have a 3-way grouping to find the mean wait_time given city, weekday and time. This is something that's fairly straightforward to do in python pandas, but I can find very little documentation on it in R (and unfortunately I need to do it in R, not python).

I've looked into using `data.table` but that hasn't seemed to work. Is there a simple function like there would be in python pandas (eg. `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).mean()`)?

Comment: Something like `df %>% group_by(city, weekday) %>% mutate(MeaD = mean(wait_time))` with `dplyr` but please post useful code. Your code has only `NA`s in wait time and only one city and only one day. With this date is impossible to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that! Fixed now. I will test this out shortly.

Comment: Should be more like `sapply(strsplit(as.character(x_output$timestamp), split = " "),'[',2)` to extract the second element from each vector in the list.

Comment: What is the criteria to group by `timestamp`? every day? every 12 hours? every week?

Comment: One more thing: you are asking 3 things (slightly unrelated), while the title is only about grouping data. Maybe it is better for you open another question (or do a search) about how to parse the `timestamp` column as a date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mean `wait_time` grouped by city, weekday, time:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(x_output, .(city, weekday, time), summarize, avg=mean(wait_time))
```

If you wanted `data.table`

```
x_output[, list(avg=mean(wait_time)), .(city, weekday, time)]
```

> I'm having difficulty creating the `time` column given `x_output$timestamp`

Well, what is the `time` column supposed to have in it? Just the time component of `timestamp`? Is `timestamp` a POSIXct or a string?

If it is a POSIXct, then you can just convert to character, specifying the time format:

```
x_output$time <- as.character(x_output$timestamp, '%H:%M')
# or as.factor(as.character(...)) if you need it to be a factor.
# in data.table: x[, time:=as.character(timestamp, '%H:%M')]
```

This will make the `time` column a string with the hour and minutes. See `?strptime` for more options on converting that datetime to a string (e.g. if you want to include seconds).

If it is a string, you could strsplit and extract the second component:

```
vapply(strsplit(x_output$timestamp, ' '), '[', i=2, 'template')
```

which will give you "HH:MM:SS" as your time format. If you want to do a custom time format, probably best to convert your `timestamp` string into a POSIXct and back out to the specific format like already mentioned.

Comment: The timestamp -> time worked perfectly. I tried both methods for the multiple groupby. Using `ddplyr`, I received `Error in attributes(out) <- attributes(col) : 
  'names' attribute [11] must be the same length as the vector [1]`. Using the data.table, I received `Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'`. My colclasses are (POSIXlt, factor, numeric, character, character).

Comment: In that case, you must provide a reproducible example. The data you have provided in your question works fine on the code I have provided, but only has one record for each city and time.

Comment: I feel a bit iffy about randomly connecting to a mystery IP from my work computer (I tried anyway and it timed out - probably firewall). In any case, the problem appears to be associated with your specific data, so you will have to narrow down if something's malformed in there.

Comment: Ok I will look into this shortly or post the .csv elsewhere if I can't get it to work.

Comment: While I'm trying to figure this out, here's the data set and code so far: https://github.com/alexpetralia/RMV_wait_times

Comment: Your `wait_times.csv` does not have data in the format of your question, and I do not have time to wade through your shiny code to try grab out the bits that reconstruct it. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153092/meaning-of-ddply-error-names-attribute-9-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vec - looks like your timestamp is `POSIXlt`. Make it a `POSIXct` instead.

Comment: This worked. I have one final question which I'll open up a new question for. Thanks a lot for your help so far.