# Organize data with maximum and minimum values in r

Tags: r, datetime, group-by, sqldf

I have a table like this:

[image]

which is generated by following code:

```
id <- c("1","2","1","2","1","1")
status <- c("open","open","closed","closed","open","closed")
date <- c("11-10-2017 15:10","10-10-2017 12:10","12-10-2017 22:10","13-10-2017 06:30","13-10-2017 09:30","13-10-2017 10:30")
data <- data.frame(id,status,date)
hour <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(data$date),' ',fixed=TRUE)))
hour <- hour[,2]
hour <- as.POSIXlt(hour, format = "%H:%M")
```

And what I want to achieve is to select the *earliest open time* and *latest closing time* for each id. So the final result will look like this:

[image]

Currently I use sqldf to solve the problem:

```
sqldf("select * from (select id, status, date as closeDate, max(hour) as hour from data 
  where status='closed'
   group by id,status) as a
   join 
   (select id, status, date  as openDate, min(hour) as hour from data 
   where status='open'
   group by id,status) as b
  using(id);")
```

**Question1:** Is there a simpler way to do so?

**Question2:** If I select `max(hour)` as any other name rather than `hour`，the result will not be in the format of date and time, but a series of number like `1507864200`, `1507807800`. How to keep the time format while assigning different names to the columns?

Comment: Do you mean for `hour` to be a column in your data? Maybe you forgot a `data$hour <- hour` line?

Answer (score 0):

Using package `plyr`:

(for some reason, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153092/meaning-of-ddply-error-names-attribute-9-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vec), you have to convert the hour to class `as.POSIXct`, otherwise you get an error message):

```
#add hour to data.frame:
data$hour <- as.POSIXct(hour)
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(id), summarize, open=min(hour[status=="open"]),
     closed=max(hour[status=="closed"]))
```