# R language - Unrecognized Error relating rbind

Tags: r

Has anyone seen this error before? -

> Error in colnames<-(tmp, value = 1:59) : 
>     'names' attribute [59] must be the same length as the vector [0]

If yes, how can I fix with it?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.  You can check similar error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566473/names-attribute-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vector

Comment: Another question with a similar error: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51148/unable-to-provide-random-parameter-with-mlogit

Answer (score 1):

This error would occur, if you try to assign column names to an empty data.frame:

```
d <- data.frame()
colnames(d) <- 1:59
```